# Python: Finding the correct value in csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm a relatively new programmer and don't have much experience with .csv files. 
The file I have looks like this:

```
hugþekkur;181038;lo;alm;hugþekkur;FSB-KK-NFET
hugþekkur;181038;lo;alm;hugþekks;FSB-KK-EFET
hugþekkur;181038;lo;alm;hugþekkir;FSB-KK-NFFT
hugþekkur;181038;lo;alm;hugþekkra;FSB-KK-EFFT
```

I want to search for the right line according to search conditions I have.
My code looks like this:

```
import csv  
reader = csv.reader(database, delimiter=';')
for split in reader:
    if (error_word == split[4]) and (wrong_mark in split[5]) and (number_mark in split[5]) and (infl_mark in split[5]) and (pos_mark == split[2]):
        idnumber = split[1]
    if (idnumber == split[1]) and (gender_mark in split[5]) and 
   (number_mark in split[5]) and (infl_mark in split[5]):
        return split[4]
```

For some reason when I search like this it doesn't return what I expect. For example,

`if idnumber = 181038, gender_mark = "KK", number_mark = "NFET" and infl_mark = "FSB"`,

it should return the first line here. It doesn't. Also, when I skip maybe one search condition, I get results but some lines are missing, including the one I want. It doesn't seem to matter what exactly I'm looking for, I can't find it.
Does any of this make sense to you? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you are missing a big important chunk after import csv. please update than in order to assist you better

Comment: We'll need to see what you're doing to create `split`. I'm also not sure why `idnumber = 88155` would match this line - that number doesn't appear anywhere in the sample line you gave.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I added some code to make it easier to see what is happening. I get idnumber from the .csv file so it's a string. One thing I noticed: When I changed  `if (idnumber == split[1]` to `if (idnumber in split[1]` I got all sorts of results, none of which had idnumbers containing my idnumber. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper - Whoops! Been testing so many different things I put the wrong idnumber in my example.

Comment: And now under certain conditions (according to `error_word`, etc) you appear to be overwriting `idnumber`, one of your search criteria, in a way that will alter the matching process for all subsequent lines...

Answer (score 2):

The biggest gotcha is likely to be the idnumber matching.  If your variable idnumber is an int (as it seems to be if I read your "For example" line literally),  then this will not match a string:   `181038 == '181038'` evaluates to `False`. You can do that kind of thing in Perl but not in Python.  In Python, `int(idnumber)==int(split[1])` would be more reliable.

Comment: Or maybe `str(idnumber) == split[1]`. You can safely stringify an int - you can't necessarily safely integerize a string.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper:  true, but if id numbers must be integers by design, then it may actually be desirable to throw an exception when an id number is in the wrong format.